# Linkedin bot Selenium Beautiful Soup not reading email in /overalay/contact-info

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

So whenever i run the following code, it writes 'no mail found' in the email.txt file. Ive checked the classes in inspect and they're correct. Anyone has any idea what the problem could be?

'''

```
visitingProfileID = profilesQueued.pop()
    visitedProfiles.append(visitingProfileID)
    fullLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com' + visitingProfileID
    linkoverlay=fullLink+'/overlay/contact-info/'
    

    with open('visitedUsers.txt', 'a') as visitedUsersFile:
        visitedUsersFile.write(str(visitingProfileID)+'\n')
    visitedUsersFile.close()
    browser.get(linkoverlay)
    soup2=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
    with open('emails.txt', 'a') as visitedEmailFile:
        
        
        try:
            pava2=soup2.find('section', {'class': 'pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-email'})
            sto=pava2.find('a', {'class': 'pv-contact-info__contact-link link-without-visited-state t-14'}).get('href')
            visitedEmailFile.write(str(sto)+'\n')
        except:
            visitedEmailFile.write('no email found \n')
    visitedEmailFile.close()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not use beautiful soup, but you need maybe to try a little bit more with xpaths.

This works for me :

```
# driver is already on linkedin profile
contact_infos = []
mails = []

try:
    contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[contains(@href,"contact-info")]'
    ).click() #click on contact-info
except NoSuchElementException:
    contact_infos.append(np.nan)
    mails.append(np.nan)
else:
    contact_info = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[contains(@class,"pv-contact-info")]')
    # save everything from contact info
    contact_infos.append(contact_info.text.split('\n'))
    print(contact_info.text.split('\n'))
    try:
        mail = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"mail")]')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        mails.append(np.nan)
        # this closes window
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@type,"cancel-icon")]').click() #this closes window
        time.sleep(<rndm>)
    else:
        mail = [x.strip() for x in mail.text.split('\n')][1]
        mails.append(mail)
        print(mail)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@type,"cancel-icon")]').click() 
        time.sleep(<rndm>)
```